# how to increase performance of mysql query if we have more than 1 million records?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In User table i have more than 1 million records so how can i manage using MySQL, Symfony 1.4. Make performance better.

So that it can give quick output.

Comment: Impossible. You can't have more users than persons on this planet.

Comment: 1.000.000.000.000 users? thats more than 150 times als much as the global population? what the hell are you doing?

Comment: Impossible II. With 4 bytes for the UserId and 10 bytes for the UserName you would need a 14 TB database. Oh, and I am forgetting the actual data in the table like birthdate and real names.

Comment: sounds like a troll post... as peter said, the size of that table would be so incredible - to manage this and keep it running till now, i think you have to be a real expert - someone who don't asks such a question to the net, providing so little information. (and, i think, mysql will die before you get such a big database, although there's not rely a limit to database-size)

Comment: Wikipedia defines trillion as ambigous in en, it can be 10^12 or 10^18.

Comment: I'm just giving example of that. Suppose we have 1 million records then how can we make performance better, how can we make query faster so it's take minimum execution time

Comment: By my calculations, the earth's population will reach 1 trillion in 2622; that's only 612 years from now. What's wrong with forward planning? Lack of forward planning gave us the millennium bug and the IPv4 address shortage.

Comment: @Peter, there are only couple of hundred users, but he is storing whole genomes.

Answer (score 2):

To significantly improve performance of well designed system all you can do is increase the resources. Typically, these days, the cheapest way to do this is to distribute the task.

For example a slow thing in RDBM system is reading and writing to an from the storage (typically RDBMs systems start as I/O bound, that is, they mostly wait for data to get read or written to storage).

So, to offset, very commonly the RDBMS will allow you to split the table across multiple HDDs, effectively multiplying the I/O performance (approach similar to RAID0).

Adding more hard disks increases the performance. This goes on up to maximum I/O that your system could support (either simply because the system can not push more data through circuits or because it does need to crunch the numbers a bit when it fetches them so it becomes CPU bound; optimally you would be utilising both)

After that you have to start multiplying the systems distributing the data across database nodes. For this to work either RDBMS must support it or there should be application layer that will coordinate distributing the tasks and merging the results, but normally things would still scale.

I would say that with 512 systems you could have all trillion records effectively cached (10^12) and achieve relatively nice performance. But really you should specify what kind of performance you are looking for - there is a difference between full text searches on terra-records and running mostly simple fetches and updates. Also, for certain work 500ms (or even more) is considered good performance and then for other work it would be horrible.

Answer (score 0):

at first: theres a **big** difference between 1 trillion and 1 million.

to your performance problems: show us the query thats running slow, without seeing it, it's hard to tell whats wrong with it. what you could try:

- use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/explain.html) to get more information about your slow querys, see if they're using your indexes or if not (and if not, why not?)
- use correct and reasonable [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: select email from dirctory_email where email <> '' limit 0,10000000;
It's take too much time to load i have more than 10 MILLION user records of US

Comment: @Ankit: please edit your qestion to provide this information, so everybody will see it without reading all the commets. also, please show/explain the structure of that table and give some example entrys - provide as much (reasonable) information as you can and don't let us grill you about every piece.

Comment: @Ankit, one comment 'SELECT * FROM anywhere LIMIT 0,10000000' is pretty useless example; or in another words you are not selecting these records to present them to the user (as if you were, the performance would surely be adequate - system, however slow, would spit them out faster then the user could read); so you are probably trying to do something with them, and that should be your question - provide us with a typical transaction you need to perform well.

Comment: I think we have this options :- 1] we need to use INNODB database, Apply INDEX on fields. Select necessary & required fields only.
2] make distributed database if needed & communicate with REST (Representational State Transfer) API
3] Using LDAP

Comment: @Ankit, I would first recommend 0] actually learning system design, difference between RDBM and hierarchical systems (such as LDAP), then role and properties of indices, etc... you should not rely on using sites such as so to give you exact answers while you still have problems with basic concepts (this makes it hard for you to ask good questions)